# Retain delimiters in node js

Tags: node.js

How to retain the delimiters ? I have to split the string and store in an array with delimiters

My code is:

```
array = data.toString().split(/\<|\>|\\>|<\/|\t|\//);
```

I also tried this:

```
array = data.toString().split(/\<|\>|\\>|<\/|\t|\/+;/);
```

Comment: The split function removes these delimiters, you can add them back once you have split the input text.

Comment: Is there any way other way to split that retains delimiters? Since I have to use large file string for processing

Comment: Not automatically, no. You would need to iterate over the string yourself, identify the indexes of your delimiter characters and then use something like [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to extract all the parts you need.

Comment: array = data.toString().split(/(\<|\>|\\>|<\/|\t|\/)/); worked for me.